# Is it possible to bind events during element concatenation in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KHeZY/199/)

The following is an example where several buttons are rendered via a loop. I was wondering if it is possible to bind events to each button as well during the loop before the buttons are appended to a container. My example doesn't work.

Jquery

```
function render(){

   var input = '',
       array = [{'name':'Confirm','title':'This'},{'name':'Cancel','title':'That'}] 

   $.each(array,function(k,obj){
       var name = obj.name;
       input += '<h3>'+obj.title+'</h3>';
       input += '<input type="submit" name="'+name+'" value="'+name+'"/>';

       $(input).find('[name="'+name+'"]').click(function(){

           alert(name)
           /*** do some ajax things etc ***/

       })

   })

   return input;
}

$('#box').append(render())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but I wouldn't do it the way you are:

```
function render(target){

   var array = [{'name':'Confirm','title':'This'},{'name':'Cancel','title':'That'}] 

   $.each(array,function(k,obj){
       var name = obj.name;
       var h3 = $('<h3/>').text(obj.title);
       var input = $('<input/>')
                     .attr('type', 'submit')
                     .attr('name',name)
                     .val(name);

       input.click(function() {alert('test');});

       target.append(h3);
       target.append(input);
   })

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    render($('#box'));
});
```

So create jquery objects that will be rendered, then attach the event to these objects. Then once the object is built ask jquery to render them.

This way jquery can keep track of the DOM elements, in your example your stringfying everything. Jquery hasn't built the DOM element at the point where your attempting to bind to them.

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skhyqyjh/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `filter()` to find the element by the name as there is no parent selector to `find()` within:

```
$(input).filter('[name="' + name + '"]').click(function(){
    alert(this.name)
    /*** do some ajax things etc ***/
})
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't bind event handlers to strings. You will need to create HTML elements first. I would recommend to bind single delegated event handler after your HTML string is appended, it's also going to be much better in terms of performance:

```
function render() {

    var input = '',
        array = [{'name': 'Confirm','title': 'This'}, {'name': 'Cancel','title': 'That'}]

    $.each(array, function (k, obj) {
        var name = obj.name;
        input += '<h3>' + obj.title + '</h3>';
        input += '<input type="submit" name="' + name + '" value="' + name + '"/>';
    });

    return input;
}

$('#box').append(render()).on('click', 'input[name]', function() {
    alert(this.name);
    /** do some ajax things etc **/
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/KHeZY/200/

Answer (score 1):

This can be done properly by using `event-delegation`, But since you concerned, I just written a solution by using `.add()` and `.filter()`

```
function render() {

    var input = '',
        array = [{
            'name': 'Confirm',
            'title': 'This'
        }, {
            'name': 'Cancel',
            'title': 'That'
        }],
        elem = $();

    $.each(array, function (k, obj) {
        var name = obj.name;
        input += '<h3>' + obj.title + '</h3>';
        input += '<input type="submit" name="' + name + '" value="' + name + '"/>';
        elem = elem.add($(input));
        input = "";
    });

    elem.filter("[name]").click(function () {
        alert(this.name);
    })

    return elem;
}

$('#box').append(render())
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KHeZY/202/)